# Sql column without foreign key reference

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

In my database I need to create one table which will contain temporary data, and later on part of that data will be deleted. That table will contain IP column. The problem is that I store IP in other table already, and its referenced in many other tables. So if I create foreign key constraint in my new table (the one which will contain temporary data) and delete row later on, I will have unuseful IP-s in original table if the new column has foreign key reference.

**Table1** columns:

```
  IP,
  Col1
```

**Table2** columns:

```
  IP,
  Col1,
  Col2
```

So my question is, Is it a good approach to create columns without foreign key reference when needed? Is it ok db design not to create foreign key reference in Table2 for IP column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is acceptable in some circumstances to create columns without the FK reference, the issue you may face is that as there are no constraints you can delete data from one table and have orphaned records in another.

Also there is nothing to enforce that the data you enter in one table exists in the other either.

The main question here is that although you store IP in other tables, do you need to join your new table to the existing table using the IP column? If no then you have no use for the FK.

Comment: There is no need for me to join the new table in any way. After satisfying one condition, the data from new table will be deleted. No joins and no use of that data later on.

Comment: Then you have no need for a FK :)

Comment: I knew that from start :) but is it a good db design? I have never seen that approach anywhere.

Comment: Its good design if you dont need the relationship between the two tables, just because you have two matching sets of data doesn't automatically mean they have to have a relationship. In your case it sounds to me like the FK would provide you no benefit

Comment: Yes, that's how exactly sounds like too me too :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using one table to store session data, and another table to store data about the IP more permanently.

You can use the IP in the session table as a foreign key to the table with more information about the IP. This will be useful if you want to query information regarding all of the people that are using your application at that time.

Comment: Yes, but i do not need data from new table. After satisfying one condition the data from that table are deleted. No need for joins